# merge all objects with same name and add its value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Take a look at below array

```
[{x: 'SomeName-1', value: 2}, 
 {x: 'SomeName-2', value: 3}, 
 {x: 'SomeName-1', value: 5},
 {x: 'SomeName-2', value: 8},
 {x: 'SomeName-1', value: 1},
 {x: 'SomeName-3', value: 4}]
```

how can i format this array so i will get `x` repeating single time with the addition of all its value.
So the result will look like below

```
[{x: 'SomeName-1', value: 8}, {x: 'SomeName-2', value: 11}, {x: 'SomeName-3', value: 4},]
```

Thnaks in advance...

Comment: You could start by showing us what you have tried.

Comment: As you can see this question has been asked a few (hundred?) times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reduce in order to group your values based on your `.x` property. Something as following:

```
const newList = list.reduce((items, item) => {
    const {x, value} = item;
  const itemIndex = items.findIndex(item => item.x === x)
  if(itemIndex === -1){
    items.push(item);
  } else {
    items[itemIndex].value += value;
  }
  
  return items;
}, []);
```

Or take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/08ka13qh/1/)

Comment: This mutates the objects in the original array.